Get associated roadway from sidewalk geometries in QGIS using OpenStreetMap data
I work with pedestrian network data from OpenStreetMap for cities where sidewalks have already been mapped as separate lines for all corresponding streets at least for parts of the city area (examples: Paris, Warsaw, Berlin, Oslo, Seattle, Manhattan, Melbourne). I'm using QGIS Graphic Modeler.
To use the corresponding network data for routing, I need to know which roadways to exclude for pedestrians because of existing (mapped) sidewalks. Unfortunately, the corresponding tags sidewalk=separate, sidewalk:both=separate, sidewalk:left=separate and sidewalk:right=separate are still missing within large portions of the given examples, so there is no attributive approach to exclude these roadways from the pedestrian network.
This is why I need a geometric approach to detect the corresponding roadways. My idea was to buffer the sidewalks up to the maximum distance between roadway and sidewalks in the given network and to detect all roadways that are located within at least two of the buffer polygons.
My geometry expression currently looks like this:
array_length(overlay_within(@Buffer_sidewalks_OUTPUT,$geometry)) >= 2

Running it on the network that has been split with lines, the result is already quite close to what I need. One of the main problems that persist is that like this, I can only detect roadways with associated sidewalks on both sides. What would be the approach to solve this for roadways that have sidewalks either to the left-hand or the right-hand side?
I found a hint to do it using perpendicular lines in the last comment here. However, I did not find a solution yet to implement this using QGIS geometry expressions. Any hints pointing me to the right direction are welcome.
My test data for Seattle can be downloaded here

Could you use single sided buffers?

Thank you. I did not know that this exists! Here's what it looks like for a part of Municipio 7 in Milano. I'll give it a try!
